# installing pidgin - Package libdrm-nouveau1 cannot be removed

Tags: 10.04, pidgin

when i trying to install pidgin client, the installations paused and an error appeared.

It says `Package libdrm-nouveau1 cannot be removed."` ..

can you all help me?

Answer (score 0):

go into your package manager. I use the muon package manager and sometimes have had to select packages & to purge couple times or more to work, should be an option instead of uninstall.

Also try apt-get autoremove